# Expresión regular para validar porcentaje en input (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, validación

Como lo dice el titulo necesito validar que el numero ingresado en un imput sea adecuado para un porcentaje. Lo estoy tratando de hacer con una expresion regular pero hasta el momento no logro que funcione correctamente. Por ejemplo al ingresar números sin decimales, me indica que es incorrecto, cuando sería un valor valido para un porcentaje.

**Valores que considero permitidos:**

- Concuerda con 100, 100.0 y 100.00
- Números como 0, 15, 99, 3.1, 21.67
- NO se deben permitir `,`, letras ni ningún otro tipo de caracteres. Solo números y un punto. Solo precisión de 2 decimales máximo.

La expresión regular que logre construir y estoy utilizando es:

```
 (^100(\.0{1,2})?$)|(^([1-9]([0-9])?|0)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)
```

A continuación dejo un pequeño ejemplo del código:

```js
function checkValue(){
  var strporc = document.getElementById("txt_porcentaje").value
  var isValid =  strporc.match(/^(100(\.0{1,2})?|([0-9]?[0-9](\.[0-9]{1,2})))$/) == null ? false:true;
  console.log("Permitido: "+isValid);
 }
```

```html
<label for="txt_porcentaje">Porcentaje:</label>
<input type="text" id="txt_porcentaje" oninput="checkValue();">
```

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Un input type number con un min 0 y Max 100 no sirve ?

Comment: @JackNavaRow no, no es valido por que me permite ingresar por ej: "22,5" y me genera error si ingreso uno valido como "25.5".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acá te paso el código funcionando:

```js
function checkValue(){
  var strporc = document.getElementById("txt_porcentaje").value
  var isValid =  strporc.match(/^((100(\.0{1,2})?)|(\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?))$/) == null ? false:true;
  console.log("Permitido: "+isValid);
 }
```

```html
<label for="txt_porcentaje">Porcentaje:</label>
<input type="text" id="txt_porcentaje" oninput="checkValue();">
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Genial!!! muchas gracias @Gustavo Cantero. Justo había logrado resolverlo usando `strporc.match(/^(100(\.0{1,2})?|[0-9]?[0-9]|([0-9]?[0-9](\.[0-9]{1,2})))$/)` . Pero la verdad que no entiendo ni que estoy haciendo. Debería estudiar [JavaScript RegExp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). Saludos!